# REMITA API integration with DJANGO for receiving payment from users

Tags: html, json, python-3.x, django

Good day all, am currently working on a project with django(python) that involves payments with remita(only). I have gone throuh remita documentations, but ...

1. Users will create account and make payment,
2. Get a response with json response instead of webhook, and save to django model

am able to make payment but am not getting response from the transact performed.
Please i need help.
Thanks in anticipation

payment.html

```
 <title>make Payment</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
       .button {background-color: #1CA78B;  border: none;  color: white;  padding: 15px 32px;  text-align: center;  text-decoration: none;  display: inline-block;  font-size: 16px;  margin: 4px 2px;  cursor: pointer;  border-radius: 4px;}
       input {  max-width: 30%;}
    </style>
 
    <div class="container mt-3">
       <h2>Remita Checkout Demo</h2>
       <p>Try out our Payment Gateway</p>
       <form onsubmit="makePayment()" id="payment-form">
          <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
            First Name: {{request.user.first_name}}
          </div>
          <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
             
             Surname: {{request.user.surname}}
          </div>
          <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="js-email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">
           <label for="email">Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-floating mt-3 mb-3">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="js-narration" placeholder="Enter Narration" name="narration">
             <label for="pwd">Narration</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-floating mt-3 mb-3">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="js-amount" placeholder="Enter Amount" name="amount">
             <label for="pwd">Amount</label>
          </div>
          <input type="button" onclick="makePayment()" value="Submit" button class="button"/>
       </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://remitademo.net/payment/v1/remita-pay-inline.bundle.js"></script>
 





<script>         
        function makePayment() {
            var form = document.querySelector("#payment-form");
            var paymentEngine = RmPaymentEngine.init({
                key: 'QzAwMDAyNzEyNTl8MTEwNjE4NjF8OWZjOWYwNmMyZDk3MDRhYWM3YThiOThlNTNjZTE3ZjYxOTY5NDdmZWE1YzU3NDc0ZjE2ZDZjNTg1YWYxNWY3NWM4ZjMzNzZhNjNhZWZlOWQwNmJhNTFkMjIxYTRiMjYzZDkzNGQ3NTUxNDIxYWNlOGY4ZWEyODY3ZjlhNGUwYTY=',
                transactionId: Math.floor(Math.random()*1101233), // Replace with a reference you generated or remove the entire field for us to auto-generate a reference for you. Note that you will be able to check the status of this transaction using this transaction Id
                customerId: form.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value,
                firstName: "{{request.user.first_name}}",
                lastName: "{{request.user.surname}}",
                email: form.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value,
                amount: form.querySelector('input[name="amount"]').value,
                narration: form.querySelector('input[name="narration"]').value,
                onSuccess: function (response) {
                  console.log('callback Successful Response', response);
                  console.log(response.dataType);
                  $.ajax({
                      type: 'post',
                      url: "{% url 'ReceivePayment' %}",
                      data: JSON.stringify({
                          'amount': amount,
                          'transactionId': transactionId,
                          'firstName': firstName,
                          'lastName': lastName,
                          'email': email,
                          'narration': narration,
                      }),
                      // data: JSON.stringify({
                      //     'amount': amount,
                      //     'transactionId': transactionId,
                      //     'firstName': firstName,
                      //     'lastName': lastName,
                      //     'email': email,
                      //     'narration': narration,
                      // }),
                      dataType: 'json',
                      success: function(response){
                          console.log("Paystack payment successful, server sent a response");
                          console.log(response);
                          let verified = response.verified;
                          let deposited = response.deposited;
                          console.log(verified);
                          console.log(deposited);
                          
                          if (verified == true){
                              window.location.href = "{% url 'login' %}";
                          }else{
                              window.location.href = redirect_url + '?ref=' + ref;
                          }

                      },
                      error: function(error){
                          console.log(error);
                          
                      }
                  });
              

                },
                onError: function (response) {
                    console.log('callback Error Response', response);
                    
                },
                onClose: function () {
                    console.log("closed");
                }
            });
             paymentEngine.showPaymentWidget();
        }
       
        window.onload = function () {
            // setDemoData();
        };
    </script>
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def initiate_remita(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    if request.method == "POST":
       
        payment_form = PaymentForm(request.POST)
        user = request.user
        if payment_form.is_valid() and user.is_valid():
            print("\n \n Payment form is valid")
            payment: Payment = payment_form.save() and user.save()
            return render(request, 'auth_system/make_paymen.html', {'payment': payment, 'remita_public_key': settings.REMITA_PUBLIC_KEY})
    else:
        payment_form = PaymentForm()
        user  = request.user
    return render(request, "auth_system/initiate-remita.html", {"payment_form": payment_form, 'user':user},)
```

models.py

```
class RemitaPayment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    narration = models.CharField(choices=narration, max_length=200, null=True, default='narration')
    rrr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Payment: {self.amount}"
```

forms.py

```
class PaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    amount = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'text', 'class':'form-control', 'id':'js-amount', 'placeholder':'Enter Amount'}))
    narration = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'type':'text', 'class':'form-control', 'id':'js-narration'},), choices=narration,)    
    # narration = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'},), choices=narration,)    
    class Meta:
        model = RemitaPayment
        fields = ('amount', 'narration')
```

remita.py

```
import requests
from django.conf import settings

class Remita:
    REMITA_SECRET_KEY = settings.REMITA_SECRET_KEY
    base_url = 'https://remitademo.net/payment/v1/remita-pay-inline.bundle.js'


    def verify_payment(self, rrr, amount:int):
        path = "/transaction/verify/{}".format(rrr)

        headers = {
            "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(self.REMITA_SECRET_KEY),
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
        url = "{}{}".format(self.base_url, path)

        response = requests.get(path, headers=headers)
        
        if response.status_code == 200:
            response_data = response.json()
            return response_data['status'], response_data["data"]

        response_data = response.json()
        return response_data['status'], response_data['message']
```